# iPhone/Mac - C++ vector or NSMutableArray

Tags: cocoa, vector, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm creating an application for iPhone which needs to handle large data.
So, I would like to know which one will be better to use : C++ Vectors or ObjectiveC's NSMutableArray?
Which one will be faster to access elements, delete elements, add elements etc.
Can some one guide me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both will work similarly as far as performance goes. If you're storing Objective-C objects, you should use an `NSMutableArray`, but if you're storing anything else and need top performance, you may want to use a `std::vector`.

Comment: It's not that simple, see this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266350/how-can-nsarray-be-this-slow