# How can NSArray be this slow?

Tags: objective-c, optimization, stl

I'm coming from a C++/STL world and I wanted to check how objective-c containers are in comparison to stl.

I wanted to compare an array of numbers but the only way to add a number to an `NSArray` is using `NSNumber` which is utterly slow and drank my ram empty so I guess I need to dealloc them manually. But I don't want to test side effects so I just added `[NSNull null]` into the array.

The results of adding 10k things into array 1k times:
`NSArray` - 0.923411 seconds
`vector<int>` - 0.129984 seconds

I thought it might be allocations and deallocations so I set the number of arrays(`imax` in the code) to 1 and number of additions to 10000000(`jmax`) but it was even slower
`NSArray` - 2.19859 seconds
`vector<int>` - 0.223471 seconds

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments the constant increasing size of the array might be the problem so I made `NSArray` using `arrayWithCapacity`, but `vector` with `reserve` too and it was even slower than before(!) (`imax` = 1, `jmax` = 10000000).
`NSArray` - 2.55942
`vector<int>` - 0.19139
End edit

Why is this so slow?

My code for reference:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int imax = 1000;
    int jmax = 10000;

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    cout << "Vector insertions" << endl;

    clock_t start = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
    {
        vector<int> *v = new vector<int>();
        for(int j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
        {
            v->push_back(j);
        }
        delete v;
    }

    double interval = (clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << interval << " seconds" << endl;

    cout << "NSArray insertions" << endl;

    start = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
    {
        NSMutableArray *v = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
        {
            [v addObject:[NSNull null]];
        }
        [v dealloc];
    }

    interval = (clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << interval << " seconds" << endl;

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want speed to store ints, why not using a C array?

Comment: Storing anything, even nulls takes 10 times slower

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@JeremyP provides an excellent link and information. Always read the fish. Here's some breakdown of what's eating time, though, and what you might do about it.

First, there's the many calls to `objc_msgSend()` for dynamic dispatch. These can be avoided and you'll save some of the time (though not as much as you'd think. `objc_msgSend()` is [crazy optimized](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/)). But you'll knock maybe 5% off by skipping it:

```
  IMP addObject = class_getMethodImplementation([NSMutableArray class], @selector(addObject:));
  NSNull *null = [NSNull null];

  start = clock();

  for(int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
  {
    NSMutableArray *v = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
    {
      addObject(v, @selector(addObject:), null);
    }
    [v release];
  }
```

A lot of time is eaten up with `retain`/`release`. You can avoid that (and stick real numbers in rather than `NSNumber`) by using a non-retaining `CFMutableArray`). This will get the append times to about 2x of `vector`.

```
  CFArrayCallBacks cb = {0};
  for(int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
  {
    CFMutableArrayRef v = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &cb);
    for(int j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
    {
      CFArrayAppendValue(v, &j);
    }
    CFRelease(v);
}
```

The biggest cost of this one is the calls to `memmove()` (or the collectable version of it on the Mac).

Man, `NSMutableArray` sure is slow. How could Apple be so stupid, right? I mean, really... wait... I wonder if there's something `NSMutableArray` does better than `vector`?

Try swapping out these lines for their obvious counterparts:

```
 v->insert(v->begin(), j);

  NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:j];
  [v insertObject:num atIndex:0];
  [num release];
```

(Yes, including creating and releasing the `NSNumber`, not just using `NSNull`.)

Oh, and you might try this one too to see just how fast `NSMutableArray` and `CFMutableArray` really can be:

```
  CFArrayInsertValueAtIndex(v, 0, &j);
```

In my tests I get:

```
Vector insertions
7.83188 seconds
NSArray insertions
2.66572 seconds
Non-retaining
0.310126 seconds
```

Comment: This is such a fantastic answer. It really gets at the heart of the matter, which is trade-offs. Finding slowness in one benchmark shouldn't make you think, "Wow, this is slow!" It should make you wonder, "Hmm, what is this doing differently and why?"

Answer (score 9):

The short answer: Yes, NSArray really is quite a bit slower than C++'s STL collection classes.  This has much to do with compile time vs. runtime behaviors, optimization opportunities on the part of the compiler, and numerous implementation details.

(And, as Rob points out, NSMutableArray is optimized for random insertion and performs better than C++ for that...)

The real answer:

**Micro-benchmarks are useless for optimizing user facing applications.**

Using a micro-benchmark to make implementation decisions is the very definition of premature optimization.

You would be hard pressed to find an Objective-C app targeted to iOS or Mac OS X where CPU profiling would show any significant time spent in code paths related to NSArray, yet the vast majority of those apps use the NS* collection classes pretty much exclusively.

Certainly, there are cases where the performance of NS* aren't viable and, for that, you turn to C++/STL.

None of this is to imply that your question is invalid.   Without more context, it is difficult to say if the observed performance difference really matters (however, in my experience, just about every time a developer has asked a question based on a micro-benchmark, it has been misguided).

Oh -- and read [this as it gives a bit of insight into the implementation of *Array](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/).

Comment: While I agree with the conclusions, my tests suggest that NSMutableArray is dramatically faster than vector if you're doing random insertion. I wouldn't write off NSMutableArray as universally slow. It just isn't as fast at appending. That said, the only real-world performance problem I've ever traced back to NSMutableArray was copying it since there's no copy-on-write that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 5):

It's a fully fledged Objective-C object which means there is an overhead each time you add an object due to Cocoa's message lookup algorithm which is necessary to implement properly dynamic binding.

There's also the point that NSArrays are not necessarily internally structured as a contiguous set of pointers.  For very large arrays, NSArray performs much better (i.e. has much better big O time complexity) than C++ vectors.  Have a read of this the definitive [Ridiculous Fish Blog](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/) on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

At least some of the time is consumed in repeatedly increasing the capacity of the NSArray.  It should be faster to initialize the NSArray to the right (or at least a better) capacity initially with:

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10000];
```

Comment: You are wrong, arrayWithCapacity was actually *slower* than without, look at my edit

Comment: @Dani - Agreed.  You could remove the cost of the expansion from the comparison by preallocating both the NSArray and the std::vector and then comparing the performance.

Comment: as @Dani notes, pre-allocating can be *slower* than letting it expand. I've seen the same behavior. My suspicion is because an expanding `NSArray` isn't laid out contiguously, so it can reuse lots of little already-allocated blocks. But when you pre-allocate, it probably tries to get all the memory in one place, and that probably is too big a block for the caching system. Just my initial hunch. But in any case, preallocation is not a certain win in Foundation, and can be a lose.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int imax = 1000;
    int jmax = 10000;

    clock_t start = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i < imax; i++)
    {
        int array[jmax];
        for(int j = 0; j < jmax; j++)
            j[array] = 0;
    }

    double interval = (clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("%f\n", interval);

    return 0;
}
```

Output in my 2GHz Core2Duo iMac (compiled with LLVM):

```
0.000003
```

Comment: `int array[jmax]` is optimized by the compiler(even with -O0), what you are checking here is 10000000 `mov`s, not what I was testing for