# Re-organize NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I need to re-organize an NSMutableArray... for example my array contain the values 1,2,3,4,5.
at the end I need an array with the values (ordering like 5,1,2,3,4).The last value always come first.

How I can do that quickly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id anObject = [[theArray lastObject] retain];
[theArray removeLastObject];
[theArray insertObject:anObject atIndex:0];
[anObject release];
```

(This runs at O(N). Actually, there is never a way faster than O(N) for an array, although the NSArray may be organized as a deque when the array is small enough where you could get O(1) in the above code. This is an implementation detail one shouldn't rely on though.)

Comment: @Rob Napier- I think that NSArray uses different storage depending on the array size. It's been a while since I looked, though.

Comment: This is much faster than O(N). I'm thinking it's O(1), but it may be O(log N) (it can depend on the size of the array, which gets laid out different ways depending on the size). NSMutableArray is not implemented internally with a traditional array.

Comment: @sbooth, yeah; I deleted my original comment as I racked my brain on how it was implemented. It definitely restructures itself at some point (in the hundreds of thousands as I recall on Mac).

Comment: @Adam/@Rob: *["Inserting an element into the middle of an array takes linear time."](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-BBCCJBIF)*. Note the `insertObject:atIndex:`.

Comment: KennyTM: See the fish for the rest of the story: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/. Also see this question for my most recent performance analysis on this particular problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266350/how-can-nsarray-be-this-slow/6268062#6268062