# What is the advantage of using a C struct in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, struct

I am currently learning Objective C and I have come across the use of C structs. But, I have been wondering the answer to the following question:

What is the advantage or the point of using a C struct if we can create Objective C classes instead?

For example, the following C struct:

```
struct date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
```

There is an `NSDate` class for this. So what is the point of C structs like the one above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the C struct to C or C++ libraries that you've directly linked into your program, such as the Unix system calls.

UIKit and Foundation use many C structs such as CGRect and NSRange.

An NSArray of NSNumbers is much more expensive than a simple C array of numbers. You would't want to represent a drawing context as an NSArray of NSArrays representing rows of NSNumbers representing pixels. You want a concise description of the raw bits.

Comment: "An NSArray of NSNumbers is much more expensive than a simple C array of numbers." -- It *can* be much more expensive. It highly depends on what you're trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6268062/97337 But you're correct that for some common use cases, C data types have less overhead and so are preferred for some kinds of performance-critical work.

Comment: @RobNapier And if you are on any of the 64 bit platforms, those NSNumbers won't require allocation at all and, thus, the NSNumbers will be even faster than allocating and storing a struct!

Answer (score 0):

The reasons to use C structures in an Objective C project are:

1. Interacting with another language, for example in a Game project that uses C, C++, etc
2. To communicate with some Apple Frameworks: Quartz Core, etc

...

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself what is the point of using, say, `double`? A `double` is an abstract data type (it has multiple bits internally stored in a format you don't need to know) and is passed around by value. You could use object-based floating point numbers (e.g. `NSNumber`), but for standard math why would you?

How about a fraction or a complex number? That's probably represented by two floating point numbers. Should it behave like a `double` - stack allocation, pass by value - or like an object - heap allocation, pass by reference? Would behaving like `double` make most sense, they're just numbers after all...

Now consider a point, that's also probably represented by two floating point numbers - value type or object type behaviour? Apple went with value type for `NSPoint`, look at its definition and you'll see its a `struct`. Is it the right choice in your view?

If `NSDate` just stored a year/month/day then Apple may have picked a `struct`, but with its calendar and timezone support its a bit more than that. However `NSTimeInterval` is a value type (and not even a `struct`, just an alias for `double`).

Where you draw the boundary between what should be a value type and what should be an object type is somewhat subjective. But in general if the type is "number like" then using a value type might well be a good, or the better, choice.